# Angular2 Routing error/missing component

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Link to full project without modules: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eaesfz4wvixusn5/EbayClone.zip?dl=0

I'm trying to add a webpage that is called "LogInPage" just for testing purposes.
After running npm start, I get this error which basically says that I should add a "LogInPage" file to the nodes_modules folder. After I do that, I get another error that says missing "async". I'm not sure if my routing is correct because I have tried importing the "login component" but it says it's missing from nodes_modules.

Screenshot of error while trying to load webpage:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMXWO.png)

App.component.ts code

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {LogInComponent} from 'angular2/LogInPage';

@Component({
 selector: 'LogInPageSelector',
 template: `
 <h1>{{title}}</h1>
 <nav>
 <a [routerLink]="['LogIn']">Log in</a>
</nav>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 `,
 styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css'],
 directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],

})
@RouteConfig([

 {path: '/LogIn', name: 'LogIn', component: Component, useAsDefault: true},

])
export class AppComponent {
 title = 'Ebay clone';
}
```

Code for LogInPage.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';
@Component({
 selector: 'LogInPageSelector',
 templateUrl: 'app/loginpage.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['app/loginpage.component.css']
})
export class LogInComponent {
 constructor(private LogInService: LogInComponent, private _router: Router) { }
}
```

loginpage.component.html code:

```
<html>
 <h1>Hello</h1>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forgot to include the "router.dev.js" file in your main HTML file:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
```